# Lent phone; won't charge

Tags: scam

Today at the train station, a guy asked to borrow my phone to call his father to pick him up.  I dialed the number and put it on speaker, but forgot to protect my own caller id and the number went to the receiving cell phone.  Now, for some weird reason, my phone won't charge.  Help?

Comment: Have you tried: turning it off and on, unplugging the cable (at both ends) and plugging it back in, and using a different cable?

Comment: I did turn it off and on just now.  The cable is fine, but since 3pm it only charged about 25%.  It seems to be charging a little faster, but I've never had this issue before.  I'm just nervous that I got scammed when I lent my cellphone.

Comment: The battery won't charge with electric current or the mobile account balance cannot be recharged?

Comment: techraf -- battery

Comment: Occam's razor rules : Replace charger cable and check again. Charger cable such as usb cable will not last forever.

Comment: The old borrowed phone battery kill; haven't seen that in a while. Just kidding, there is no such thing; relax.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there is a concern that in the act of allowing a call to an untrusted number to be made from the phone that the phone was exposed to an attacker who may have used that number to direct an exploit, the results of which a potential change in chargeability is a symptom of something deeper.

So- a failure to charge as quickly is often just some app going on the fritz and consuming more power than it should. Check your power settings and see what's top of the list.

In terms of compromises-

It is possible to direct exploits to phone numbers- SMS and MMS machinery has been vulnerable across a number of products and models in the past.

And it is possible, even common, for attackers to identify specific targets and use social engineering techniques to engage them in a transaction that leads to a compromise.

That said, the likelihood of any particular situation, barring unusual circumstances, actually being a compromising incident, is vanishingly low.

My suggestion if the concern remains top of mind- make the mistake of calling the number back, asking for a name of someone you know, but listen to see if it was really "dad" on the other side. When it turns out to be ok, apologize for the misdial.